# can't find button with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, automation, bots

This is really throwing us. I am working on an indeed application bot and we are hung up on finding the apply now button in the html. Right now, the bot clicks a job post in the left pane- this opens the post in the right pane. The bot then switches focus to the iframe that the button element is in. Then, when it tries to find the button, it breaks, and goes on to the next job post. We've used TAG_NAME, CLASS_NAME, XPATH, CSS_SELECTOR, and so on. Nothing works. really loosing it.

Here is our code that should be finding the button:

```
try:

        ### find Easy apply button
        print('clicked on post')
        rightPane = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.jobsearch-RightPane')))
        terminalLogger(message='right pane found')

        #debugging here: 
        # try:
        #     driver.switch_to.frame(rightPane)
        #     terminalLogger(message='switched to right pane')

        # except Exception as e:
        #     print(f"An exception occurred: {e}")
        
        iframe = driver.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value='iframe')
        terminalLogger(message='iframe found')
        
        driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
        terminalLogger(message='switched to iframe')

        # application_btn = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='button.css-1bm49rc.e8ju0x51')
        try:

            application_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@class="css-1bm49rc e8ju0x51" and @aria-label="Apply now opens in a new tab"]')))


            application_btn.click()
            terminalLogger(message='Easy Apply button found')

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


        #switch focus to new tab
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        easyApply(driver)

    except:
        terminalLogger(message='Easy Apply button not found') 
        #undo switch to iframe
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        terminalLogger(message='switched focus back to default content')
        pass
```

The HTML is on this page on indeed:

https://www.indeed.com/

Comment: This violates [Indeed's terms of service](https://www.indeed.com/legal). Please obey the terms.

Comment: I won't actually use this bot. This is hypothetical.

Comment: @John Hurley thats what they all say ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from image, the "Apply Now" button is not contained in a `iframe` node.

[image]

So you can easily click with

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'indeedApplyButton').click()
```